# Is it relatively simple to design an ADC to ADAT interface with only a Toslink port?

Tags: audio, music, recording, digital-audio

For this project (I'm an experienced audio engineer but a relative beginner in electrical engineering) I really want to integrate a simple ADC to ADAT circuit in a patchbay I'm building so that I have 8 balanced TRS line inputs that I can patch into. No USB control needed, essentially the circuits that you find on any of the 8 channel preamps that have adat functionality added. If it's possible to get timecode off of the ADAT connection alone that would be great, something that works with interfaces like the Universal Audio Twins that only have an ADAT input is where I want to end up. I've looked into the Cool Audio ICs for the ADC and the ADAT generator, specifically the M8000 (https://www.coolaudio.com/features-page.php?product=M8000) and the V1401 (https://www.coolaudio.com/features-page.php?product=V1401), but I'm a bit lost on if I can successfully put them together in a straightforward and cost effective way. Again, very unexperienced in these matters but willing to learn and I'd like to think I have a general enough understanding to follow your answers. Any help would be much appreciated!

Also this seems to be a similar question but unsure if it squares up the same as mine [V1401 ADAT transmitter and PCM4222 ADC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/460508/v1401-adat-transmitter-and-pcm4222-adc)

Comment: MAY be useful or interesting [cct](https://www.beis.de/Elektronik/ADDA24QS/Images/AD24QS_sp.GIF) from [here](https://www.beis.de/Elektronik/ADDA24QS/AD24QS.html)

Answer (score 1):

Those two chips are a good choice and would do the job, but as for being “relatively simple”? No, and certainly not for a “relative beginner in electrical engineering”. If nothing else, you’d have to make a fairly intricate surface mount PCB with not only these two chips but all the peripheral stuff: power supplies, clocks, audio preamps (mic? line? hi-Z?) And then put it in a box and power it from somewhere.

But assumingly you could do all that, you’d want to generate your own 44.1KHz or 48KHz clock domain (word, bit, and master clocks), configure the ADC in master mode, and route the four i2s outputs into the ADAT transmitter (configured to use 24 bit format). The Apollo Twin would then need to be set to use your incoming ADAT as its clock source.

I commend you for finding good chips for doing this, but I would gently dissuade you from undertaking this rather audacious project unless you really want to do it for fun and learning. Otherwise, go to Sweetwater and plunk down $400 for the Focusrite OctoPre.